# MySQL Workbench - вопрос по программе

Tags: mysql, ide

Есть такая проблемка, при написании запросов в MySQL Workbench появляются красные кресты либо зеленые стрелки, хотя запросы рабочие (скриншот моего компа фото 1). В отличие от видеоурока, там у человека возле каждого запроса голубые кружки, видимо сигнализирующие о правильности запроса. Как это исправить?

**Мой скриншот:**
[image: фото 1]

**Скриншот** из MySQL Workbench другого человека:
[image: фото 2]

Comment: И где у вас тут красные кресты?

Comment: @PinkTux вместо зеленых стрелок красные квадраты с крестами, не знаю как они пропали, запросы наверняка были правильные.